# az login passed authentication, but does not authenticate subsequent commands

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am new to Azure DevOps and I am trying to upload a universal package using the following script on my Windows machine:

```
az login --tenant xxxxxxxxxx

az artifacts universal publish ^
    --organization https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/ ^
    --feed LibWin64 ^
    --name LibWin64 ^
    --path C:\work\Lib ^
    --version 1.0.0
```

I passed authentication in browser, but the scripts stopped after `az login` displayed JSON with my tenant details, probably because `az login` returned an error code.
If I ran `az artifacts universal publish` after that, I got the following error:

```
TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\myemail in a web browser to enable access to the service.
```

Then I generated an access token with full access rights and tried `az devops login`:

```
echo oijoijjoijoijoijoijoijpojoj | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/

az artifacts universal publish ^
    --organization https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/ ^
    --feed LibWin64 ^
    --name LibWin64 ^
    --path C:\work\Lib ^
    --version 1.0.0
```

This time `az devops login` did not return any error, but `az artifacts universal publish` throws the same error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which system are you using windows or other?

Comment: On Windows. I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you refer the commands and pre-requisite from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) and use PAT token from your Azure Devops organization to login into your Azure devops account with Azure CLI command.

***I used below commands to login and publish artifacts into my Devops organization and it worked successfully like below:-***

```bash
az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738

az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/ --feed feed-name --name package-name --version 1.0.0 --path "C:\Users\username\Downloads\7z2301-x64.exe" --description package-description
```

---

> After running az devops login command the cli will prompt you to add PAT Token copy your pat token and click right click on your mouse to
> paste it and click enter you will be successfully logged in

---

**Output:-**

**Make sure you are using correct feed id**
[image]

You can create a PAT token with Artifact access like below:-

Assign build and package roles or according to your requirement  create a PAT token and save it somewhere for login.

[image]

Comment: Tried all of this. No success.